# Sublime Text plugin API: how to get list of files in project?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for Sublime Text 2/3 that should open multiple files which names contain a certain string.

How could I get a list of the files in the project? I can't find any related API function in the docs. I can do it with Python's `os.walk` but it's kinda slow. On the other hand, Sublime's `Ctrl+P` menu is blazingly fast, but I don't know how to access its contents from my plugin.

Comment: I don't know any documentation about the API but SideBarEnhancements plugin has 'File: Search Files': 'side_bar_find_files_path_containing' command which is defined in SideBarEnhancements/SideBar.py. You should check it if it's related at all to what you want. Edit: After sending this I realized maybe this is not even close to what you want.

Comment: I agree. It's utterly annoying that the sublime fuzzy search is so fast but that a plugin developer has no access to that through the API. Have you discovered something yet? Good luck.

Comment: @Rob Nope. I've given up on this, at least for now.

Answer (score 4):

In Sublime Text 3 [API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) fot exists function for get files in project, but exists function `project_data()` which returns project related information. for files you can code like this:

```
project_data = sublime.active_window().project_data()
project_folder = project_data['folders'][0]['path']
# and here os.walk(project_folder )
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I tried but I wasn't satisfied with performance on large project. I'm certain that Sublime has a cached list of files for Ctrl+P menu, but it looks like it doesn't provide an access method for that. Hmmm, maybe I should make my own cache :)

Comment: @LONGMAN You have some access to the symbols via `window#lookup_symbol_in_index`, `window#lookup_symbol_in_open_files`, and `view#symbols` in ST3.

Comment: Can I get all indexed symbols in project?

Comment: It cannot even get symbols that are used in every file... the window and view methods seem pretty useless unfortunately